# При парсинге печатается не html страница, а белиберда

Tags: python, requests

При парсинге страницы в консоль выдается это:

```
default/order/search/index_spa.twig
```

вместо html разметки.

Есть подозрения, что дело в строении страницы, ибо на других все работало.
Мой код если интересно:

```
import requests
import fake_useragent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LINK = 'https://a24.biz/login'  # ссылка на действие авторизации
USER = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random

DATA = {'ci_csrf_token': '19ef1de90dd7fc024af4baf0602bae2e',
        'email': 'какой-то имэйл',
        'password': 'какой-то пароль'}
#  Я зарегестрировал аккаунт если что
URL = 'https://a24.biz/order/search'

HEADERS = {'user-agent': USER}

session = requests.Session()

responce = session.post(LINK, data=DATA, headers=HEADERS).text

auction_page = 'https://a24.biz/order/search'
auction_response = session.get(auction_page, headers=HEADERS).text
print(auction_response)
```

Можно ли это исправить, и если нет - то почему?

Comment: csrf_token при каждой сессии случайный и он довольно крипто устойчивый, его можно найти на странице авторизации или он выдаётся через специальный запрос, но это надо смотреть работу логики сайта.
Инструменты разработчика и вкладка network в помощь

Comment: @Georgiy Спасибо.(хотя я бы посоветовал расписывать чуть подробнее, например в ответах, ведь не все полезут гуглить и читать как я.) Т.е мне надо один раз вручную вписать токен, а затем с помощью кукисов входить дальше, так?

Answer (score 0):

Как то так проходит авторизация. Здесь токен выдают через запрос, а не генерацией на странице.

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
# получение cookies
s.get("https://a24.biz/login")
# дополнительный headers для успешных запросов
s.headers.update({"referer": "https://a24.biz/login"})
# получение csrf токена
token = s.get("https://a24.biz/ajax/getCSRFToken").json()["ci_csrf_token"]
r = s.post("https://a24.biz/login", data={"ci_csrf_token": token,
                                          "email": "foobar@bar.ru",
                                          "password": "123456"})
```

Comment: Попробовал. Любо я что-то неправильно делаю, либо дело не только в токенах.

Comment: У меня аккаунта нет проверить, но авторизация проходит, по неверным данным выдаёт в ответе что такого email не существует